# jquery Using ranges in switch cases?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Switch cases are usually like

```
Monday: 
Tuesday: 
Wednesday: 
etc.
```

I would like to use ranges.

```
from 1-12: 
from 13-19:
from 20-21:
from 22-30:
```

Is it possible? I'm using javascript/jquery by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use ranges in a switch case statement using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could try abusing the switch fall through behaviour

```
var x = 5;
switch (x) {
    case  1: case 2: case 3: case 4: ...
        break;
    case 13: case 14: case 15: ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

which is very verbose

or you could try this

```
function checkRange(x, n, m) {
    if (x >= n && x <= m) { return x; }
    else { return !x; }
}

var x = 5;
switch (x) {
    case checkRange(x, 1, 12):
        //do something
        break;
    case checkRange(x, 13, 19):
    ...
}
```

this gets you the behaviour you would like.  The reason i return `!x` in the else of checkRange is to prevent the problem of when you pass `undefined` into the switch statement.  if your function returns `undefined` (as jdk's example does) and you pass `undefined` into the switch, then the first case will be executed.  `!x` is guaranteed to not equal `x` under any test of equality, which is how the switch statement chooses which case to execute.

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but upon searching for an answer to the same question, I came across this thread.  Currently I actually use a switch, but a different way.  For example:

```
switch(true) {
    case (x >= 1 && x <= 12):
        //do some stuff
        break;
    case (x >= 13 && x <= 19):
        //do some other stuff                
        break;
    default:
        //do default stuff
        break;
}
```

I find this a lot easier to read than a bunch of IF statements.

Comment: You can't do it like this in JavaScript, it won't evaluate the expressions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - it works just fine in every test case I've thrown at it.

Comment: @zuallauz Check the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-switch-statement) — both _⟨expr1⟩_ and _⟨expr2⟩_ in `switch(` _⟨expr1⟩_ `){ case` _⟨expr2⟩_ `: break; }` are expressions which are all evaluated. This has been the case since ECMAScript 3rd edition. Prior to that, JavaScript didn’t even have a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can make interesting kludges. For example, to test a number against a range using a JavaScript switch, a custom function can be written. Basically have the function test a give n value and return it if it's in range. Otherwise returned undefined or some other dummy value.

```
<script>

// Custom Checking Function..
function inRangeInclusive(start, end, value) {
    if (value <= end && value >= start)
        return value; // return given value
    return undefined; 
}

// CODE TO TEST FUNCTION
var num = 3;
switch(num) {
case undefined:
    //do something with this 'special' value returned by the inRangeInclusive(..) fn
    break;
case inRangeInclusive(1, 10, num):
    alert('in range');
    break;
default:
    alert('not in range');
    break;
}

</script>
```

This works in Google Chrome. I didn't test other browsers.

Comment: @barkmadley: I just edited the code and added a case for the undefined value to explicitly handle it. There might be a better return value to use in the inRangeInclusive(..) function. Open to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need to use an if/else if series to do this. JavaScript isn't this fancy. (Not many languages are.)