# How can I use ranges in a switch case statement using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, intervals

How can I use ranges in a switch case statement using JavaScript? So, instead of writing code for each and every single possibility, I'd like to group them in ranges, For example:

```
switch(myInterval){
   case 0-2:
      //doStuffWithFirstRange();
      break;

   case 3-6:
      //doStuffWithSecondRange();
      break;

   case 6-7:
      //doStuffWithThirdRange();
      break;

   default:
      //doStuffWithAllOthers();
}
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You have at least four options:

### 1. List each `case`

As [shown by LightStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145741/157247), you can list each case explicitly:

```
switch(myInterval){

    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        doStuffWithFirstRange();
        break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        doStuffWithSecondRange();
        break;

    case 6:
    case 7:
        doStuffWithThirdRange();
        break;

    default:
        doStuffWithAllOthers();
}
```

### 2. Use `if` / `else if` / `else`

If the ranges are large, that gets unwieldy, so you'd want to do ranges. Note that with `if...else if...else if`, you don't get to the later ones if an earlier one matches, so you only have to specify the upper bound each time. I'll include the lower bound in `/*...*/` for clarity, but normally you would leave it off to avoid introducing a maintenance issue (if you include both boundaries, it's easy to change one and forget to change the other):

```
if (myInterval < 0) {
    // I'm guessing this is an error
}
else if (/* myInterval >= 0 && */ myInterval <= 2){
    doStuffWithFirstRange();
}
else if (/* myInterval >= 3 && */ myInterval <= 5) {
    doStuffWithSecondRange();
}
else if (/* myInterval >= 6 && */ myInterval <= 7) {
    doStuffWithThirdRange();
}
else {
    doStuffWithAllOthers();
}
```

### 3. Use `case` with expressions:

JavaScript is unusual in that you can use expressions in the `case` statement, so we can write the `if...else if...else if` sequence above as a `switch` statement:

```
switch (true){

    case myInterval < 0:
        // I'm guessing this is an error
        break;    
    case /* myInterval >= 0 && */ myInterval <= 2:
        doStuffWithFirstRange();
        break;

    case /* myInterval >= 3 && */ myInterval <= 5:
        doStuffWithSecondRange();
        break;

    case /* myInterval >= 6 && */ myInterval <= 7:
        doStuffWithThirdRange();
        break;

    default:
        doStuffWithAllOthers();
}
```

I'm not advocating that, but it *is* an option in JavaScript, and there are times it's useful. The `case` statements are checked **in order** against the value you give in the `switch`. *(And again, lower bounds could be omitted in many cases because they would have matched earlier.)* Even though the `case`s are processed in source-code order, the `default` can appear anywhere (not just at the end) and is only processed if either no `case`s matched or a `case` matched and fell through to the default (didn't have a `break`; it's rare you want to do that, but it happens).

### 4. Use a dispatch map

If your functions all take the same arguments (and that could be no arguments, or just the same ones), another approach is a dispatch map:

In some setup code:

```
var dispatcher = {
    0: doStuffWithFirstRange,
    1: doStuffWithFirstRange,
    2: doStuffWithFirstRange,

    3: doStuffWithSecondRange,
    4: doStuffWithSecondRange,
    5: doStuffWithSecondRange,

    6: doStuffWithThirdRange,
    7: doStuffWithThirdRange
};
```

Then instead of the switch:

```
(dispatcher[myInterval] || doStuffWithAllOthers)();
```

That works by looking up the function to call on the `dispatcher` map, defaulting to `doStuffWithAllOthers` if there's no entry for that specific `myInterval` value using [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), and then calling it.

You can break that into two lines to make it a bit clearer:

```
var f = dispatcher[myInterval] || doStuffWithAllOthers;
f();
```

I've used an object for maximum flexibility. You *could* define `dispatcher` like this with your specific example:

```
var dispatcher = [
    /* 0-2 */
    doStuffWithFirstRange,
    doStuffWithFirstRange,
    doStuffWithFirstRange,

    /* 3-5 */
    doStuffWithSecondRange,
    doStuffWithSecondRange,
    doStuffWithSecondRange,

    /* 6-7 */
    doStuffWithThirdRange,
    doStuffWithThirdRange
];
```

...but if the values aren't contiguous numbers, it's much clearer to use an object instead.

Answer (score 22):

The ranges in this example are pretty small, but here's how one can handle larger ranges, per the [JavaScript MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```js
// The value we'll be evaluating:
let code = 100;

// Matches for any case where the expression === `true`:
switch (true) {
  case code <= 64:
    return "Your number is 64 or less!";
    break;
  case code >= 65 && code <= 90:
    return "Your number is in the range of 65-90!";
    break;
  case code >= 97 && code <= 122:
    return "Your number is in the range of 97-122!";
    break;
  case code >= 123:
    return "Your number is 123 or greater!";
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

I know that this style was already shown by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145931/6685623) via ***Use `case` with Expressions***, but I just wanted to show another example of how to utilize this same method. I just did this and had thought maybe another example might help someone, as I was still a little confused after reading other replies.

Answer (score 7):

Is this maybe what you need?

```
switch(myInterval){

    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        //doStuff();
        break;

    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        //doStuff();
        break;

    case 6:
    case 7:
        //doStuff();
        break;

    default:
        //doStuff();
}
```

If you know the range is going to be very high(for example `0-100`) you can also do this, which is surely easier, cleaner and simpler:

```
if (myInterval >= 0 && myInterval <= 20) {
    //doStuff();
} else if (myInterval > 20 && myInterval <= 60) {
    //doStuff();
} else if (myInterval > 60 && myInterval <= 70) {
    //doStuff();
} else /* it is greater than 70 */ {
    //doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your ranges are the same and start from 0 you can do some math.

```
doStuffWithRange(Math.floor(myInterval/range));
```

For example, if you want RED, GREEN, and BLUE to the map like your example:

- Range 0-2 maps to RED
- Range 3-6 maps to GREEN
- Range 7-8 maps to BLUE

You can write:

```
function colorInterval(n, max) {
     var colors = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"];
     var range = max/colors.length
     return colors[Math.floor(n/range)];
 }

//You get 3 of RED, 3 of GREEN, 2 of BLUE
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    console.log(colorInterval(i, 8));
}
```

Note that the last range in the example is 2, not 3 and this still works as long as the previous ranges are the same.

Comment: While this solution isn't that flexible (ranges have to be the same), it's still an interesting idea. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of diversity to the excellent answers already posted, especially as the intervals starts with 0, here is a solution with `findIndex` ([Yeah ES6](https://2ality.com/2013/12/array-prototype-find.html)):

```js
const range = [0, 2, 6, 7];
const randeIndex = range.findIndex(threshold => myInterval <= threshold);
switch (rangeIndex) {
  case 1:
    //doStuffWithFirstRange();
    break;

  case 2:
    //doStuffWithSecondRange();
    break;

  case 3:
    //doStuffWithThirdRange();
    break;
  default:
  //doStuffWithAllOthers();
}
```

Because the `range` array is ordered, `findIndex` will match the first one. Depending on how you *name* your ranges, stating from 0 or 1, you may need to remove the first 0 in `range`.

Comment: Good idea, but writing the findIndex function parameter like that makes it unclear what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

Use case statement with defined string or value or use "if else if", in case range is higher

Comment: This should've been posted as a comment.

Answer (score -3):

int levelNumber = YOUR_VALUE FROM

```
NSString* strMessage;

switch (levelNumber) {
    case 1...10:
    {
        // Do something...
        break;
    }
    case 11...20:
    {
        // Do something...
        break;
    }
    case 21...30:
    {
        // Do something...
        break;
    }
    case 31...40:
    {
        // Do something...
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

**Refer:** 
https://www.codingexplorer.com/loops-switch-statements-ranges-swift/

Comment: I tried this solution but receive an error with both `...` and `..` separating the values of the range. I don't believe the syntax is valid, as convenient as it would be...

Comment: this is not a valid syntax

Comment: Updated syntex,  there were extra space between ... and number. Now changed

Comment: This is for Swift; the question is for JavaScript.