# Odd behavior with else if statement (javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return-value, comparison-operators

As far as I can tell the code works fine normally but when more information is added or edited then the if else statement starts behaving oddly. It's reading the percent value correctly but it's not returning the correct letter string.

```
var total = function (){
    var earned = 0;

     for(i = 0; i < Assignments.length; i++){
         earned += parseInt(Assignments[i].earned);
     }
     var possible = 0;

     for(i = 0; i < Assignments.length; i++){
         possible += parseInt(Assignments[i].possible);
     }
     var percent = (Math.floor((earned/possible) * 100));

     console.log(percent);

  //grade letter

      if (percent >= 90){
         grade.innerHTML = '';
         grade.innerHTML = 'A ' + percent + '%';
      } else if (percent <= 89 && 80 >= percent){
         grade.innerHTML = '';
         grade.innerHTML = 'B ' + percent + '%';
      } else if (percent <= 79 && 70 >= percent){
         grade.innerHTML = '';
         grade.innerHTML = 'C ' + percent + '%';
      } else if (percent <= 69 && 60 >= percent){
         grade.innerHTML = '';
         grade.innerHTML = 'D ' + percent + '%';
      } else if(percent <= 59 && 0 >= percent){
         grade.innerHTML = '';
         grade.innerHTML = 'F ' + percent + '%';
      } else {grade.innerHTML = '';}



};
```

After a few inputs it will return something like this:

[image: B is = 73%? Noo!]

I think it might be the else if statements conflicting, but honestly I have no idea why this is behaving this way.

Comment: what's conflicting? What is returned that you don't want to? How, in exact way is it going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use a switch-statement? It's much easier to read than a lot of if/else-blocks.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: @WhiteBr0wnie_24 How do you use a switch with number ranges?

Comment: I agree, you'd better use a switch, that's typically the job of switch. Any if/else workaround would be really disgraceful compared to switch :)

Comment: Just using the same expressions as he did, using switch(percent) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619832/switch-on-ranges-of-integers-in-javascript

Comment: `switch(percent)` wouldn't work when `percent` is 0 (it has to be `switch(true)`.) And I wouldn't call that "the job of switch" when you hack it that way. There are better ways to test for a number range than else-if chains, but switch is not one of them.

Comment: @Juhana simply do it by switch(boolean_expression) where boolean expression can be anything that evaluates true or false. That's also something like case (grade > 10 && grade < 20). Look at my answer I posted an interesting link where this can be read.

Comment: @Juhana et. al.: While it's *possible* to use a `switch` for this in JavaScript (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17145931/157247, see #3), it's just a long-winded `else if`.

Comment: @Juhana So, what are the " better ways to test for a number range than else-if chains" ?

Comment: Seeing the second answer of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619832/switch-on-ranges-of-integers-in-javascript), this could make this code a lot more readable and efficient.

Comment: @enguerranws T.J.'s answer has one good method (or more generally an object/array which you iterate over). The switch(true) method is exactly the same as else-if chain only with "case" in place of "else if".

Answer (score 6):

You have your comparisons backward in the `else if`s, you're using `70 >= percent` rather than `percent >= 70` (and so on).

Separately, there's no reason to assign `''` to `innerHTML` if you're about to assign something else to it, and there's no reason to reiterate the upper bound (`percent <= 89` and such), because you're using `else if`, so the `percent >= 90` branch will have already been followed. Reiterating them is also a maintenance problem (you'll change one but forget to change the other).

So:

```
if (percent >= 90) {
    grade.innerHTML = 'A ' + percent + '%';
} else if (percent >= 80) {
    grade.innerHTML = 'B ' + percent + '%';
} else if (percent >= 70) {
    grade.innerHTML = 'C ' + percent + '%';
} else if (percent >= 60) {
    grade.innerHTML = 'D ' + percent + '%';
} else if (percent >= 0) {
    grade.innerHTML = 'F ' + percent + '%';
} else {
    grade.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Or of course, you can use a map, since your grade boundaries are evenly divisible by 10:

```
// Somewhere central
var grades = {
    6: 'D',
    7: 'C',
    8: 'B',
    9: 'A',
    10: 'A'
};

// ...then simply:
if (percent >= 0) {
    grade.innerHTML = (grades[Math.floor(percent / 10)] || 'F') + ' ' + percent + '%';
} else {
    grade.innerHTML = "Less than 0?!";
}
```

```js
var grades = {
    6: 'D',
    7: 'C',
    8: 'B',
    9: 'A',
    10: 'A'
};

function showGrade(percent) {
  var grade;
  if (percent >= 0) {
    grade = (grades[Math.floor(percent / 10)] || 'F') + ' ' + percent + '%';
  } else {
    grade = "Less than 0?!";
  }
  snippet.log(grade);
}

var n;
for (n = 0; n <= 100; ++n) {
  showGrade(n);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: The "map solution" is the best IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

`If-Else` condition range looking wrong, try this code...

```
var total = function (){
var earned = 0, possible = 0;
for(i = 0; i < Assignments.length; i++){
     possible += parseInt(Assignments[i].possible);
     earned += parseInt(Assignments[i].earned);
 }
 var percent = (Math.floor((earned/possible) * 100));

 console.log(percent);

  //grade letter

  if (percent >= 90){
     grade.innerHTML = 'A ' + percent + '%';
  } else if (percent >= 80 && percent <= 89){
     grade.innerHTML = 'B ' + percent + '%';
  } else if (percent >= 70 && percent <= 79){
     grade.innerHTML = 'C ' + percent + '%';
  } else if (percent >= 60 && percent <= 69){
     grade.innerHTML = 'D ' + percent + '%';
  } else if(percent >= 0 && percent <= 59){
     grade.innerHTML = 'F ' + percent + '%';
  } else {grade.innerHTML = '';}
};
```

Although i have optimized some code no need 2 loops there, you can sum `earned`, `possible` variable in single loop, and no need to `.innerHTML = ''` when you assigning value in  element.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice post on efficiency using different methods of comparing things. I still suggest using a switch-block instead of if/else, but it's technically not better than your solution, but as I thinks it nicer to read. Here is a code snippet:

```
switch (true) {
case (0 <= val &&  val < 1000): /* do something */ break;
case (1000 <= val &&  val < 2000): /* do something */ break;
...
case (29000 <= val &&  val < 30000): /* do something */ break;
}
```

Taken from this post. There's also an interesting table (in the first answer)
[Switch statement for greater-than/less-than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than)
and different methods of making this work. I know this is actually not a solution for your answer, but it might come in handy if you need to add more if/else and are doing some huge lists with values.

Comment: Repeating the boundaries lays this wide open to maintenance bugs. But you can do the same thing *without* repeating the boundaries, in JavaScript `switch` cases are evaluated *in order* and only the first matching one is executed (as with `else if`).