# Is there in javascript to use includes in an if statement or switch?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app to check the expiration dates of items. The functionality of the app works but I want to be able to check if a string includes a sub-string in order to run my function which is a countdown timer. I haven't included much of the code but it should be sufficient. Code is Bellow

```
var userInput = prompt("What item would you like to look up?");
  switch (userInput) {
    case userInput.includes("cous cous"):
//run a setInterval function
```

Comment: The the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript), including [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript/17145931#17145931). Yes you can. But you probably shouldn't. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case expression:` resolves the expression and does an equality test of that value against the `userInput`.

Use an `if()` statement for this type of thing.