# using switch for grading

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

am trying to make an output of grades using switch
but there is an error idk why it didn't work it shows me the default message
i checked : and break but i still dont know the error
so i need some help 
thanks

```js
<script>
    var grade=0;
    
    grade=window.prompt("Enter your grade");
    
    switch(grade)
        {
             case grade>= 95:
                document.write("You got A+");
                break;
                
            case grade<95 && grade>= 90:
                document.write("You got A");
                break;   
            
            case grade<90 && grade>=85:
                document.write("You got A-");
                break;
                
            case grade<85 && grade>=80:
                document.write("You got B+");
                break;
                
            case grade<80 && grade>=75:
                document.write("You got B");
                break;
            
            case grade<75 && grade>=70:
                document.write("You got B-");
                break;
                
            case grade<70 && grade>=65:
                document.write("You got C+");
                break;
                
            case grade<65 && grade>=60:
                document.write("You got C");
                break;
                
            case grade<60 && grade>=55:
                document.write("You got C-");
                break;
                
            case grade<55 && grade>=50:
                document.write("You got D");
                break;
                
            case grade<50:
                document.write("You FAILED");  
                break;
                
             default:
                document.write("Wrong Number"); 
        }
</script>
```

message and i need some help 
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use ranges in a switch case statement using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make the same code but changed

```js
switch (grade)
```

to

```js
switch (true)
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

What the `switch` does is, finds what is the exact match.
When you use `switch(grade)`, this finds the exact match of `'grade'` all the way, as it fails, it goes to `default`.

If you want to use `switch(grade)`, you need to write all the values to cases.

Why `switch(true)` works?
It matches which condition is true then gets the result.