# Switch...case in JS

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

This simple problem gives me an error. Does not get the correct answer. I will be glad if you help.

```
let point = 90;
switch (point) {
    case point >= 51 && point <= 60:
        console.log('Your price: E');
        break;
    case point >= 61 && point <= 70:
        console.log('Your price: D');
        break;
    case point >= 71 && point <= 80:
        console.log('Your price: C');
        break;
    case point >= 81 && point <= 90:
        console.log('Your price: B');
        break;
    case point >= 91 && point <= 100:
        console.log('Your price: A');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('You did not pass');
}
```

`Output:` You did not pass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use ranges in a switch case statement using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript)

Comment: Please read on how to use switch. There is now a trick to do it, but the way you do it is absolutely not how to use it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way

```js
let point = 90;
switch (true) {
    case point >= 51 && point <= 60:
        console.log('Your price: E');
        break;
    case point >= 61 && point <= 70:
        console.log('Your price: D');
        break;
    case point >= 71 && point <= 80:
        console.log('Your price: C');
        break;
    case point >= 81 && point <= 90:
        console.log('Your price: B');
        break;
    case point >= 91 && point <= 100:
        console.log('Your price: A');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('You did not pass');
}
```

> can you explain why we write `true`? – Hussein Nadjafli (PO)

The JS `switch` only works on strict equality.

```
switch (A) {
   case ‘x1’: ...
   case ‘x2’: ...
```

is equivalent to

```
if       (A === ’x1’) { ...
else if  (A === ’x2’) { ...
```

in your code you replace the possible values *[’x1’,’x2’,...]* with an evaluation like

```
(point >= 61 && point <= 70)
```

which returns either `true` or `false`
so your code becomes:

```
if       (A === (point >= 51 && point <= 60)) { ...
else if  (A === (point >= 61 && point <= 70)) { ...
```

by replacing the `A` by `true` you therefore have a comparison between:

```
if       (true === (point >= 51 && point <= 60)) { ...
else if  (true === (point >= 61 && point <= 70)) { ...
```

---

> You can also do:

```js
function codePrice(val)
  {
  let code = 'ABCDE'[10 - Math.ceil(val / 10)]
  return (!!code) ? `Your price: ${code}` :'You did not pass'
  }

console.log( codePrice(90) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Can also be simplified:

```js
let point = 90;
switch (true) {
    case point < 51:
        console.log('You did not pass');
        break;
    case point < 61:
        console.log('Your price: E');
        break;
    case point < 71:
        console.log('Your price: D');
        break;
    case point < 81:
        console.log('Your price: C');
        break;
    case point < 91:
        console.log('Your price: B');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Your price: A');
        break
}
```

Comment: The only logic here is to find the same responses to the same input values, which is not the case in your code